# Is this proof of $\epsilon$-greedy policy improvement correct?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, epsilon-greedy-policy, policy-improvement-theorem

The following paragraph about $\epsilon$-greedy policies can be found at the end of [page 100, under section 5.4](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=122), of the book "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction" by Richard Sutton and Andrew Barto (second edition, 2018).

> but with probability $\varepsilon$ they instead select an action at random. That is, all nongreedy actions are given the minimal probability of selection, $\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}$, and the remaining bulk of the probability, $1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}$, is given to the greedy action. The $\varepsilon$-greedy policies are

So, the non-greedy actions are given the probability  $\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}$, and the greedy action is given the probability $1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}$. All clear up to this point.

However, I have a doubt in the policy improvement theorem that is mentioned in page 101, under section 5.4. I have enclosed a copy of this proof for your convenience:

$$
\begin{aligned}
q_{\pi}(s, \pi^{\prime}(s)) &=\sum_{a} \pi^{\prime}(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+(1-\varepsilon) \max _{a} q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
& \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+(1-\varepsilon) \sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a \mid s)-\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}}{1-\varepsilon} q_{\pi}(s, a)\\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+\sum_{a} \pi(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
&=v_{\pi}(s) .
\end{aligned}
$$

My question is **shouldn't the greedy action be chosen with a probability of $1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}$**?

The weighing factors do not add up to 1, as they are probability values. With this argument, the proof (with a slight modification) would be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
q_{\pi}(s, \pi^{\prime}(s)) 
&=\sum_{a} \pi^{\prime}(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+ \left( 1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \right) \max _{a} q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
& \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+\left(1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}  \right) \sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a \mid s)-\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}}{1-\varepsilon+\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}  } q_{\pi}(s, a)\\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+\sum_{a} \pi(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
&=v_{\pi}(s) .
\end{aligned}
$$

Though the end result isn't changed, I just want to know what I am conceptually missing, in order to understand the proof that is originally provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weights *do* sum to one. Note that in the second line where we have 
$$\frac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_a q_{\pi}(s,a) + (1-\epsilon)\max_aq_{\pi}(s,a) \; ,$$
the sum is over the whole action space, including the greedy action, so the sum of the weights will be $\frac{\epsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \times |\mathcal{A}(s)| + (1-\epsilon) = 1$.